# Why the name O for category O?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, etymology

What is the motivation behind naming the category O appearing in the theory of Lie algebras? Does O stand for something? 
Here is a question [Why the BGG category O?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64931/why-the-bgg-category-o) that further confuses me. It seems like there is a notion of when a category is O, is it?

Comment: The category is in some sense generated by modules arising from sheaves of holomorphic sections of line bundles. So maybe the question is why are the sheaves of holomorphic sections denoted by $\mathcal{O}$?

Comment: @VítTuček, isn't that because of something like "O for olomorfe"?

Comment: I think that the $\mathcal O$ notation comes from the notation for rings of integers in number fields, probably standing for "order" ("Ordnung" in German).

Comment: I thought it was O for Oka...

Comment: Four comments, four different answers... I guess that proves this question is worthy of an authoritative answer!

Comment: the [paper](https://books.google.nl/books?id=YdvrGF_S4G0C&pg=PA513) by Bernstein, Gelfand & Gelfand that introduces category O just says: "We shall call this category of $g$ modules the category O."

Comment: @CarloBeenakker, can you also link to a pdf of the paper at http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~bernstei/Publication_list/Publication_list.html?

Comment: Someone (Mirkovic?  I'm not sure) told me that when they discovered it, they said "Oh, that's the right category!"  This was probably a joke, but is my preferred explanation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [Humphreys: Representations of semisimple Lie algebras in the BGG category O], notes for Chapter 1:

> The letter chosen to label the category is the first letter of a
>   Russian word meaning “basic”

which is основной.